# Open same View Controller

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, swift4, xcode9

Using Xcode 9 / Swift 4, I have a *tile application* (same as Windows 10 presentation).

When user is on main view controller and click on a tile, I want to open **the same** view controller and set parentId, in order to show **child tiles**.

App can have infinite number of child of child.

But, app crash when I try to push same View Controller as current displayed:

```
let vc = currentStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TileViewController") as! TileViewController

vc.parentId = id
vc.title = item.name

currentViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
```

Comment: Are you trying to push a navigation controller to a navigation controller?

Comment: You must have some crash logs.

Comment: you should also paste the code also

Comment: What error do you get when it crashes?  Where is that code you show in your app?  How are you creating the tiles (uiCollectionView, manually, etc)?  Give us something to work with.

Comment: Crash log is : Uncaught exception: Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint. This is strange because current ViewController is TileViewController but I don't have crash. Only when I try to push it from new instance.

Answer (score 0):

The exception your are having its not related of pushing the same instance another time. Well you are probably adding some constraints programmatically, And also its being added in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear because thats what can i understand from the exception that your getting:

```
Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
```

If its so then you'll need to add it in either `updateViewConstraints()` which is called when the view controller's view needs to update its constraints, or inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`.